# Doubly linked list c++

Tags: c++, xcode, doubly-linked-list

```
/*
```

The below code is only printing the adresss and not the actual data. 
I could not figure out where i am missing something.
 Also, i was wondering how do i insert data next the existing node. It only lets me add data to the front not the back.

*/

## include

```
using namespace std;

typedef string Elem;                // list element type
class DNode {                   // doubly linked list node
private:
    Elem elem;                  // node element value
    DNode* prev;                // previous node in list
    DNode* next;                // next node in list
   friend class DLinkedList;            // allow DLinkedList access
};

class DLinkedList {             // doubly linked list
public:
    DLinkedList();              // constructor
    //~DLinkedList();               // destructor
    bool empty() const;             // is list empty?
    const Elem& front() const;          // get front element
    const Elem& back() const;           // get back element
    void addFront(const Elem &e);       // add to front of list
    void addBack(const Elem& e);        // add to back of list
    void removeFront();             // remove from front
    void removeBack();              // remove from back
    void print() const;
private:                    // local type definitions
    DNode* header;              // list sentinels
    DNode* trailer;
protected:                  // local utilities
    void add(DNode* v, const Elem &e);      // insert new node before v
    void remove(DNode* v);          // remove node v
};



DLinkedList::DLinkedList() {            // constructor
    header = new DNode;             // create sentinels
    trailer = new DNode;
    header->next = trailer;         // have them point to each other
    trailer->prev = header;
}

//DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() {         // destructor
//    while (!empty()) removeFront();       // remove all but sentinels
//    delete header;                // remove the sentinels
//    delete trailer;
//}
void DLinkedList::addFront(const Elem &e)   // add to front of list
{ add(header->next, e); }

void DLinkedList::addBack(const Elem& e)    // add to back of list
{ add(trailer, e); }


bool DLinkedList::empty() const     // is list empty?
{ return (header->next == trailer); }

const Elem& DLinkedList::front() const  // get front element
{ return header->next->elem; }

const Elem& DLinkedList::back() const       // get back element
{ return trailer->prev->elem; }

//// insert new node before v
void DLinkedList::add(DNode* v, const Elem &e) {
    DNode* u = new DNode;  u->elem = e;     // create a new node for e
    u->next = v;                // link u in between v
    u->prev = v->prev;              // ...and v->prev
    v->prev->next = v->prev = u;
}

void DLinkedList::print() const
{
    DNode * nodePtr;

    nodePtr = header;

    while (nodePtr) {

        cout<<nodePtr->prev<<endl;

        nodePtr = nodePtr -> next;
    }


}

int main()
{
    DLinkedList list;

    list.addFront("2334");
    list.addFront("apple");

    list.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen? You're passing a pointer @ `cout << nodePtr->prev << endl`.

Comment: addBack works fine for me. Using debian linux gcc 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Its printing adress because you are printing the address. Change your cout statement in print() function

```
while (nodePtr) {
        cout<<nodePtr->prev->elem<<endl;
        nodePtr = nodePtr -> next;
    }
```

Also any reason to typedef sting to Elem ?

Comment: You mean `cout<<nodePtr->prev->elem<<endl;`

Comment: It is giving me this error :         learning(10801,0x7fff7acb1300) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8029759185026510848) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Program ended with exit code: 0